# Views and random numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table below where it outputs all the players within all teams that are playing in week 1, league 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
FROM dbo.Fixture f
INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1 and l.LeagueID = 1
```

This just outputs a long list and what I require are the following which I am not sure how to do as I am a beginner when it comes to t-sql:

- Out of all the players (there are 20 players per team), only select a random set of 11 players per team. Out of the 11 players however, there must the required number of positions:

1 GK, 4 DF, 4 MF, 2 FW (These letter abbreviations are determined by the field ‘Position’ where each player is assigned a position)

Then what I want is display the teams pitted against each other. For example if in week 1, teamID 1 is playing teamID 4, then display side by the 11 players from team 1 against the 11 players in team 4. Do this for the rest of the teams. The fixtures are already set in the fixtures table (Screenshots attached)

How can this be achieved?

Fixture table:

[image]

Current Query results:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiT2Ouu36TNAhWLWRQKHS93AXEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms186734.aspx&usg=AFQjCNF80R8zK_CIPIcKmIVIcLL0CRHLlA&sig2=SGuMhUNozDTx0qqVZqJhDg&bvm=bv.124272578,d.d24&cad=rja) to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT tt.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tt.teamID,tt.position ORDER BY newid()) as rnk
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber,
        FROM dbo.Fixture f
        INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
        WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1 and l.LeagueID = 1) tt) s
WHERE (s.position = 'GK' and s.rnk = 1) OR 
      (s.position = 'DF' and s.rnk <= 4) OR
      (s.position = 'MF' and s.rnk <= 4) OR
      (s.position = 'FW' and s.rnk <= 2)
```

This will rank each group `(teamID,position)` randomly,  and the last `WHERE` clause will pick 1 `GK` , 4 `DF`, 4 `MF`, 2 `FW` .